# Merge [vaio] into [sony-vaio]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[vaio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vaio) (x11) should be merged into [sony-vaio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sony-vaio) (x93) and be made a synonym thereof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

```
updating post history, 19 rows affected
updating posts, 12 rows affected

tag remapping of [sony-vaio] and [vaio] complete!

Tag Synonym vaio -> sony-vaio was approved!
```